# How to sign jar and adding manifest attribute for read, write?

Tags: java, jar, applet, desktop, code-signing

I am new to this forum. You have obeserved from jan-2014 due java security update we getting the error on running self signed jar files.

I have tried to sign an jar containing applet applications with following steps

1. I have created a keystore
2. created code signing request(CSR) and purchased certificate from the certificate authorities.
3. downloaded root certificate and intermediate certificates.
4. later i have imported all certificates as trusted certificates into keystore
5. with the help of keystore i have signed my jar containing applets.

While running code saying some codes not signed. But may be there is a problem with the manifest files with permission. please check my steps and help me correct method sign jar. If you have code signing links with certificates or in personal help will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html) is the doc on the manifest file and what you need to put into it.  All jars that get downloaded need to be signed with the same certificate AND you need to update the applet tag to include permission - see [here for applet tag doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html).  This all assumes you are using Java7 update 51 or greater.  Earlier versions were showning warnings but not blocking the applet or webstart apps.